# How to get the edited text in sweetalert

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

I have a method to ask the user to edit the text,

```
swal({
      text: "Edit your Task",
      content: {
        element: "input",
        attributes: {
          value: data,
        }
      },
      buttons:{
        cancel: {
          text: 'Cancel',
          value: 'cancel'
        },
        edit:{
          text: 'Edit',
          value: 'edit'
        }
      }
    }).then((value)=>{
      console.log(value);
    })
```

This is my code, now how to get the updated input text when the user clicks the Ok button

Answer (score 1):

take a look at the Doc , https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/ at ajax requests, you need to search before ask here

Comment: I have checked it out. I am not able to get the text in the input box in the promise

Comment: try to give a class and access by $('.myclass').val()